# Getting the PayerId from Paypal Android SDK

Tags: android, paypal

Using the paypal android sdk I get this response from the paypal service:

```
{
  "client":{
     "environment":"sandbox",
     "paypal_sdk_version":"2.0.0",
     "platform":"Android",
     "product_name":"PayPal Android SDK;"
  },
  "response":{
     "create_time":"2014-02-12T22:29:49Z",
     "id":"PAY-564191241M8701234KL57LXI",
     "intent":"sale",
     "state":"approved"
},
 "response_type":"payment"
}
```

After this I need to verify that the payment went thought with my own webservice.

That webservice is an old one which was set up for Paypal Webview and expect the **PayerId** field.

I couldn't figure out how to get that.
Ideas?

Comment: Did you get answer for it?

Comment: Nope, gave up :(

Comment: How did you integrated Paypal SDK then??

Comment: We remade the whole thing (backend and frontend) using the latest recommendation from Paypal.

Comment: What is the recommended way ? Are you talking about brainTree integration

Comment: We used this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/android-integration-guide/. It was not deprecated back then. Probably now I would go with Braintree.